# Swipe event propagation with nested div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Hi I've the following html structure:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="scroller">
            <div id ="goldenPage" class="page active">              
                <div class="block text">
                    <div class="rich-text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="form"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <ul class="menu"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id ="cachePage" class="page"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

If I bind a swipe event on div with class container using code

```
var myElement = $(".container")[0];
            var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement);             
            hammertime.on("swiperight",function(){
                console.debug(" manage swiperight event.");                 
                });
```

and if I swipe nothing happen (except if I swipe on the bottom of my page because the internal div with scroller class is fewer height than parent div). If I bind the swipe on div with class scroller the swipe is correctly binded. The scroller div is binded with jquery scrollpane plugin.
Any ideas?!

Comment: So what's the question here exactly?  Are you asking why it's doing what it's doing or are you asking for a way to bind the swipe to the container div and still work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5ryp615q/) — Make sure your JavaScript/jQuery is fired after the [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event.

If the JavaScript fires before the element is available in the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), your JavaScript will not find the element, and thus be unable to bind the (`swiperight`) event to the element.

Using jQuery, this can be achieved by wrapping your JavaScript code in:

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here.
    console.log("Ready!");
});
```